# Allocating Executable Page in Linux Kernel Module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vmalloc

I know there is a relevant post about this in the following link but I am missing the header file asm/pgtype_types.h for some reason in my kernel (My kernel version is 4.9.13-v8+)

[How to allocate an executable page in a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458819/how-to-allocate-an-executable-page-in-a-linux-kernel-module)

Do you have any idea why I am missing that header file , or is there any other way ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Headers under `asm/` are rarely included directly. Have you tried to omit this inclusion? (Header `linux/vmalloc.h` defines `vmalloc`, so it should define constants which can be passed to that function).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks a lot for your answer , you are correct : the code compiles without including pgtype_types.h (I will update the post when I verify that the page is indeed executable)