# Allocating executable memory using kmalloc

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, x86-64, kernel-module

The answers to the question [How to allocate an executable page in a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458819/how-to-allocate-an-executable-page-in-a-linux-kernel-module) describe how executable memory can be allocated using `__vmalloc()`. Is this also possible using `kmalloc()`? My goal is having a physically-contiguous executable memory area.

Comment: IIRC, `kmalloc` just gives you a pointer into the existing direct-mapped region that maps all physical memory.  So the question is whether this existing mapping has exec permission or not.  (IDK, could go either way.  Yes for performance: don't need separate mappings for code parts.  No for security so there isn't a kernel-executable mapping of all memory contents just sitting there waiting to be used as a "gadget" by a ROP attack or even as a Spectre gadget).

Comment: @PeterCordes It does not have exec permissions. I tried it, and dmesg shows "kernel tried to execute NX-protected page - exploit attempt? (uid: 0)"

Answer (score 0):

> It does not have exec permissions. I tried it, and dmesg shows "kernel tried to execute NX-protected page - exploit attempt? (uid: 0)"

Then no, I'd assume you can't `kmalloc` executable memory.  Unless I'm wrong about how it works (returning pointers into an existing mapping that uses 1GB hugepages to cover all of physical RAM) it's just plain incompatible with the purpose / design of `kmalloc`.

There might be something other than `vmalloc` that you could use, if you really need more than 1 physically-contiguous 4k page of executable memory, but I don't know what it is.  (I'm not a kernel dev, I just know a little bit about the big picture, and lots about CPU architecture / x86).  Perhaps something like `vmalloc` and then changing the page tables?

Other answers welcome.

Comment: Downvote this all you want; it's still (I think) correct that `kmalloc` itself never remaps page-table entries ([What is the difference between vmalloc and kmalloc?](//stackoverflow.com/q/116343)) and thus can't give you executable pages.  If there is some function that makes physical contiguous + executable possible, leaving a comment or writing an answer would be much more useful to future readers than a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

use `alloc_pages(gfp_t gfp_mask, unsigned int order)` and then make them executable manually using `set_memory_x`.

```c
void *allocate_physically_contiguous(size_t size, void * data_copy)
{
    void *ret;
    struct page *page;
    unsigned int order = get_order(size);

    flags |= __GFP_COMP;
    page = alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL, order);
    ret = page ? page_address(page) : NULL;
    if(!ret)
        return NULL;
    memcpy(ret, data_copy, size);
    // set_memory_x makes the pages executable, and also read-only, and in some archs, they won't even be readable.
    BUG_ON(set_memory_x(ret, 1 << (order - PAGE_SHIFT)));
    return ret;
}

// to free, just call `kfree(...)` on the returned pointer
```